# Google Script for opening a URL in dedicated browser (Internet Explorer) by click in Spreadsheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-applications

I am using Google Chrome (as G-Suite is used by the users for standard/collaboration processes) and I am looking for a Google Script that opens a URL out of Google Spreadsheet in a new internet explorer application.

Background: I have a Google Sheets document with lots of tabs. The first tab is the "landing page", linked to the tabs and to external Google Documents or other URLs, using macros / Google Script. The problem is that I have one online application that only runs in Internet Explorer. So I need to have a script forcing to open the URL in a new  Internet Explorer application.
Everything I found was on how to open a new window or tab, but I did not find anything saying "open a url in a dedicated browser" (here: Internet Explorer). I am looking for something like the script below, I used for opening external links out of Google Spreadsheets, but additionally saying "do this with Internet Explorer":

```
function open link in new window() {
var js = " \
<script> \
window.open('https://www.externalwebapplicationthatonlyrunsonwindowsexplorer.com', '_blank', 'width=800, height=600'); \
google.script.host.close(); \
</script> \
";
var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(js)
.setHeight(10)
.setWidth(100);
SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'Loading, please wait...');
}
```

Comment: Opening with a specific application is under the purview of  your OS(Windows/Mac/linux). You may be able to set defaults in your OS settings.  Voting to migrate to https://superuser.com

Comment: Thanks!. But in this case - if I understand you well - I do not need a "one fits all" solution but to open IE only for one specific website. Meaning I want to create & assign a specific "open link in IE"-macro/Google Script to an object (clickbox). Alll other links of my "landing page" to other Google documents (e.g. Spreadsheets) or external websites should still be opened with chrome.

Comment: It's not possible to control that from Google script. It may be possible from OS settings or VBA macro. JavaScript doesn't have api to choose the external browser(It'll be a disaster of epic proportions(read monopoly, fragmentation), if it did).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it's not possible to force open links in specific browser, it is possible to detect the user agent string as the [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57725845) states. You can use use [HtmlService.getUserAgent()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-service#getUserAgent()):

```
function testInternetExplorer(){
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(js)
    .setHeight(10)
    .setWidth(100);
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var response = ui.alert('This app link is available only on Internet Explorer.\n Proceeding to use outdated browsers may cause serious damage to your device, data  and privacy.\nAre you sure you want to continue?', ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
  if(response == ui.Button.YES) {
    if(/Trident|MSIE/.test(HtmlService.getUserAgent())){
     ui.showModalDialog(html, 'Loading, please wait...');
    } else { 
     ui.alert("Internet Explorer is not detected.\n Cannot proceed.")
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried the script and assigned it to a click box. I receive the following error message: "ReferenceError: js is not defined". Any idea?

Comment: @Syntax Declare variable `js` (inside `testInternetExplorer` function) as declared in your question

Comment: Of course. Now it works. Will add the link of the application to be opened with IE in the text so at least the user knows 1.) why the application does not open and 2.) how to open it manually. Thanks again.

Comment: @Syntax If I were you, I'd consider removing the application altogether. Any app that works only on IE is not worth having, IMO. Consider accepting the answer, if it works.

Comment: Brilliant as always, I missed `.getUserAgent()` in the HtmlService documentation. Though I agree with @TheMaster even for legacy reasons having an app only run in IE is asking for all sorts of trouble.

Comment: @Rafa Thinking again, even without `.getUserAgent()`, OP is already  using client side scripts. So, We can do everything client side script in the modal dialog html file: `if(/MSIE|Trident/.test(navigator.appName + " " + navigator.userAgent)){window.open("ieOnlyWebApp link")} else(alert('Need IE...'))`

Comment: @TheMaster. If it would be my private decision I would do so immediately. But it is part of a stone old programmed application where no one wants to spend any money to rewrite/update the app as everyone is fearing additional costs...Further discussion on the meaning of this management behaviour would be endless and OT i fear...But i fully agree with you. I shortened your code to just display the error message as I realized that there is no usecase to click the script from a IE environment. So not having the "right" programm is the standard case and no check needed thus.

Comment: @Syntax ok. Just to confirm- my script opens your web-app on IE and on chrome throws " Cannot proceed ", when called from a button Right? If that solves your question, you can [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) the answer as working.

Comment: The script informs that the browser used is not IE and thus "Cannot proceed". I modified to directly give "Cannot proceed" without testing the Browser, as stated in my last comment. Will accept as working - even if it cannot solve the problem. But it is a workaround I can live with and again thanks for your and Rafa's support!

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible for you to force which browser opens a link in Google Apps Script or in JavaScript - this can't be decided by a script, only the end-user that is using the device.

You can however use a conditional that only loads the script if the browser is detected to be Internet Explorer like this though:

```js
function doGet(e){
  var browser = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('index')
  var browser2 = browser.getContent();

  if (browser2.indexOf('Netscape') !== -1){
    if (browser2.indexOf('Trident') !== -1 || browser2.indexOf('MSIE') !== -1){
      // run your code
    }
  return noMessage();
  }
  else {
    return noMessage();
  }
}

function noMessage(){
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('This page will only run in Internet Explorer.');
}
```

And the `index.html`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <p id="x"></p>
    <script>
      document.getElementById("x").innerHTML = navigator.appName + " " + navigator.userAgent;
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This just checks the navigator settings for Internet Explorer-like strings and runs the script based on that. It's not a perfect workaround, but sadly forcing the browser like that is simply impossible.

Comment: Hello Rafa. 

Unfortunately I receive a  "SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier" for this part of your code:

    if browser.indexOf('MSIE') !== -1;){

Any idea? Thanks in advance! Boris

Comment: Have you tested this?

Comment: @TheMaster Yes, in IE 9 and Chrome 76.0.3809.132

Comment: I don't think it works. The script on the html is not executed, when you createHtmlOutput or when you getContent(). `browser2` will always be `<p id="x"></p>
    <script>
      document.getElementById("x").innerHTML = navigator.appName + " " + navigator.userAgent;
    </script>`( the script tags won't execute) and indexOf will always return -1

Comment: @themaster and Rafa:
Thanks for your support. So it seems I have to accept that it is not possible to force the choice of a specific browser. A bit sad as the standard application for the users is Chrome. So I will create a text box with the URL saying to open the application in the "right" Browser (in this case: IE) manually by copy pasting the link by the user.

Comment: @Syntax Rafa's idea is good and it is possible to check the user agent, just not using client side scripts. I'll add a alternative answer.